# WoW Addon (Lua) Variables and methods

Tags: lua

I've been messing with this for hours and I can't seem to get this to work

```
for i=1, 10 do
 local frame = "MyFrame"..i

 frame:EnableMouseWheel(true)
end
```

and the error I get is

```
attempt to call method 'EnableMouseWheel' (a nil value)
```

but if I do

```
MyFrame1:EnableMouseWheel(true)
```

there's no problem what so ever and it works

is there anyway to use a variable as a frame name for the method?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this is not for the 5.x client there might have been changes since then. this is for World of Warcraft patch 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
local vars = getfenv()
for i=1, 10 do
    local frame = "MyFrame"..i

    vars[frame]:EnableMouseWheel(true)
end
```

---

Although you appear to be looking for the solution to the wrong problem. Why not store them in an array to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string name into a variable name you need to access the global object as a table:

```
_G["MyFrame1"]
```

I don't know about what version of Lua warcraft uses. If its a really old version that doesn't have _G then you probably need to use the getglobal functions instead

```
getglobal("MyFrame1")
```

That said, this is usually an antipattern. If you are the one that originally defined the MyFrame variables its normally better to use an array instead:

```
Myframes = {
   MyFrame1,
   MyFrame2,
}
```

since this lets you avoid the string manipulation

```
local frame = MyFrames[i]
frame:EnableMouseWheel(true)
```